# How to find different groups in networkx using python?

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, networkx, network-analysis

i am using facebook dataset and making a graph on it. But was not been able to find different groups in it. 
The code i am using is this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.read_edgelist('facebook_combined.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
print nx.info(g)

sp = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=sp, with_labels=False, node_size=35)
# plt.axes('off')
plt.show()
```

This result i am getting is this:
[image]

Can anyone please tell me how can i find different groups in it ?

The link to the dataset is [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/facebook_combined.txt.gz)

The source of dataset is [here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Facebook.html)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Definition

Another term for groups is clusters. This is a fairly common problem.

You will have to define the clustering (or grouping) metric. One way to approach this is to define a distance metric. For example, you can use the Jaccard distance. Two nodes are close if they share common neighbors:

[image: jaccard]

[image: jaccard_dsitance]

### Distance matrix

```
import numpy as np
nn = len(g.nodes)
mat = np.empty((nn, nn), dtype=float)
mat.fill(-100.0)
np.fill_diagonal(mat, -0.0)
```

Networkx can compute Jaccard coefficients for you with `nx.jaccard_coefficient()` :

```
preds = nx.jaccard_coefficient(g, g.edges)
for u, v, j in preds:
    mat[u,v] = -100 * (1 - j)
```

### Clustering

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
np.median(mat)
af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-100, affinity="precomputed")
lab = af.fit_predict(mat)
len(np.unique(lab))
```

Result: 571 clusters

### Plotting

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
pd.value_counts(lab).plot.bar()
plt.xticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

The largest cluster contains 70 nodes.

**EDIT:**

### Community detection

It appears that you want to find communities. You may use the [`python-louvain` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-louvain) to partition the graph:

```
import community
import collections

partition = community.best_partition(g)
values = [partition.get(node) for node in g.nodes()]
counter=collections.Counter(values)
print(counter)
```

[out]:
`Counter({7: 548, 4: 543, 2: 435, 1: 431, 3: 423, 0: 350, 5: 323, 9: 237, 13: 226, 12: 206, 6: 121, 8: 73, 11: 60, 10: 25, 14: 19, 15: 19})`

You can visualize these "groups" with colors :

```
sp = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=sp, with_labels=False, node_size=35, node_color=values)
# plt.axes('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help and efforts! But here groups means i want to show different groups in the above pictures that i have posted in question.

Comment: Is it related to the spring layout ?

Comment: i want to perform further analysis so that first i decide to find different groups here but not able to do that

Comment: Maybe you can state your definition of group. Then we can help you finding them.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the communities that appear on your plot? If this is the case I can update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help man! :) I accepted your answer because your solution helps in providing the groups/communities i want to find out. Thankyou!

Comment: Moreover, can you please give me a hint that what further analysis can i perform on this question/dataset ?